# Подбор пары из блока данных

Tags: python, bash

Приветствую `%alluser%`
Есть блок данных, где 1 символ мальчик либо девочка, далее идет геном, в конце совместимость:

```
♂ h21a18d8s6sa27sd10.100T
♂ h28a20d3s10sa18sd27.100A
♂ h8a17d0s23sa16sd9.100G
♂ h12a12d7s18sa14sd17.100T
♂ h9a4d6s17sa20sd28.100G
♂ h9a18d9s26sa22sd24.100T

♀ h3a4d12s23sa24sd23.100T
♀ h22a20d25s28sa12sd28.100G
♀ h28a27d26s24sa16sd19.100A
♀ h4a8d25s28sa3sd27.100T
♀ h12a15d21s7sa16sd26.100T
♀ h14a5d21s21sa2sd18.100T
♀ h13a28d0s13sa17sd7.100G
♀ h8a13d24s11sa8sd9.100T
♀ h5a24d21s28sa11sd18.100G
♀ h18a0d12s27sa13sd1.100T
♀ h14a24d25s6sa2sd14.100G
♀ h5a1d13s8sa3sd2.100T
♀ h28a27d26s24sa16sd19.100A
♀ h13a22d21s20sa12sd27.100G
♀ h25a23d17s22sa9sd14.100G
```

Нужно найти наиболее подходящие пары, например:

```
♀ h28a27d26s24sa16sd19.100A    
♂ h13a17d11s28sa26sd4.100A
```

Интересует чтоб у пары были значения h,a,d,s,sa,sd наиболее высокими.
Как написать подобный скрипт не на bash не на python я к сожалению не знаю, очень нужна помощь.
Если нужны пояснения спрашивайте.
UPD (1) Как подступиться к данной задаче понятия не представляю, пока смог на bash осуществить перевод данных в более удобо варимый вариант:

```
♂ 28 20 3 10 18 27 A
♂ 8 17 0 23 16 9 G
♂ 9 4 6 17 20 28 G
♂ 21 18 8 6 27 10 T
♂ 12 12 7 18 14 17 T
♂ 9 18 9 26 22 24 T

♀ 28 27 26 24 16 19 A
♀ 13 22 21 20 12 27 G
♀ 25 23 17 22 9 14 G    
♀ 22 20 25 28 12 28 G
♀ 5 24 21 28 11 18 G
♀ 13 28 0 13 17 7 G
♀ 14 24 25 6 2 14 G
♀ 4 8 25 28 3 27 T
♀ 12 15 21 7 16 26 T
♀ 14 5 21 21 2 18 T
♀ 3 4 12 23 24 23 T
♀ 8 13 24 11 8 9 T
♀ 18 0 12 27 13 1 T
♀ 5 1 13 8 3 2 T
```

Чем больше значения во всех столбцах у пары тем лучше.
Желательно скрипт на bash, но и на python пойдет.

Comment: 1. почему эта пара «наиболее подходящая»? 2. как оценивается «подходящесть»? 3. что значит «наиболее высокими»? 4. на каком именно языке программирования требуется решение? 5. что вы уже сделали на пути к решению и что именно не получилось? // включите, пожалуйста, это всё прямо в ответ.

Comment: вам надо получить сумму чисел в строке?

Comment: Нет, нужно получить файл, либо вывод на экран данных:    ♀ h28a27d26s24sa16sd19.100A        
♂ h13a17d11s28sa26sd4.100A

Comment: вы, видимо, не понимаете, что непонятно в вашем вопросе. потому и не смогли дать **ясного ответа** на 1, 2 и 3 вопросы в моём первом комментарии. добавлю ещё один вопрос: что вообще у этих двух строк, которые вы привели, общего? почему они являются **парой**?

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то главным критерием "подходящести" считается последняя буква. Т.е. нужно выбрать пару с одинаковыми буквами и максимальными цифрами. Я прав?

Comment: Да правы, буквы определяют совместимость.

Answer (score 1):

Эта задача, если отбросить всё лишнее описание сводится в весьма известной задачи о назначениях. Сначала сведём, для этого нужно для каждой пары {i,j} вычислить F[i,j] - сложить что там нужно если пара возможно и -бесконечность если это сделать нельзя. 
Теперь у нас есть матрица N*M из которой нужно выбрать min(N,M) клеток, так чтобы ни в 1 строке и столбце не было выбрано 2 клетки. Добавим недостающие строки/столбцы до квадратной матрицы, заполненные -бесконечностями.
Это решается либо перебором "в лоб" - долго. Либо Венгерским алгоритмом.
http://e-maxx.ru/algo/assignment_hungary - ссылка на статью. Можете использовать любую другую статью.

Думаю после этого код написать уже сумеете.

P.S. бесконечность - достаточно большое число чтобы точно быть больше чем сумма всех чисел в задачи, но меньше чем MAX_TYPE/max(N,M) чтобы не вызвать переполнения.